# Find the value of a specific key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary

```
 customer_order = {order0 
{'Orientation': what_orientation, 'Size': what_size, 'sizecost': size_cost, 
 'eyelets': how_many_eyelets, 'eyeletcost': eyelet_cost, 'material': what_material,
 'materialcost': material_cost, 'ropes': need_ropes, 'ropecost': rope_cost, 
 'image': need_image, 'imagecost': 0, 'wording': what_wording, 'wordcost':word_cost}

order1{'Orientation': what_orientation, 'Size': what_size, 'sizecost': size_cost, 
 'eyelets': how_many_eyelets, 'eyeletcost': eyelet_cost, 'material': what_material, 
 'materialcost': material_cost, 'ropes': need_ropes, 'ropecost': rope_cost, 
'image': need_image, 'imagecost': 0, 'wording': what_wording, 'wordcost':word_cost}}
```

what I need to do is fetch the value of the following keys

```
sizecost
eyeletcost
materialcost
ropecost
wordcost
```

how do I loop through to get these values and add them to a running total?

Thanks

I tried the code below but get the error

```
for key, value in cust_details:
```

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

for cust_order, cust_details in customer_order.items():
        print("\nOrder: ", cust_order)
        for key, value in cust_details:
            if (key == "sizecost"):
                totalcosts += value

```
        if (key == "eyeletcost"):
            totalcosts += value

        if (key == "materialcost"):
            totalcosts += value

        if (key == "ropecost"):
            totalcosts += value

        if (key == "wordcost"):
            totalcosts += value
```

totalcost += value

Comment: first your dictionary is not a valid python object. Can you make it a valid python object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `recurssion`

```
def look(key,d,val = None):
    if val is None:
        val = []
    if key in d.keys():
       val.append(d.get(key))
    else:
        for i,j in d.items():
            if isinstance(j,dict):
                look(key,j,val)
    return val
```

now try calling: `look("sizecost", customer_order )`

Comment: Thanks for laying it out properly. I had put it into the template correctly but when I posted it came out rather horribly.